# Converting HTML to string with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, vb.net, string, document

I've parsed a string with HTML to a HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument, but I can't seem to convert it back to a string.

```
    Dim Document As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
    Document.LoadHtml(Result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the InnerHTML

```
Dim html As String
html = Document.DocumentNode.InnerHTML
```